# C++ Calling a child class function from a base class when I don't know the childs' type

Tags: c++, polymorphism, base-class

I have an inventory that stores 'InventoryItem's.

```
struct InventoryItem{
Item* item;
unsigned int quantity;};

std::vector<InventoryItem> m_items;
```

I add items like the following, `m_inventory.addItem(bandage);`

But when I try to call Bandages's `use()` function which has been derived from the Item base class, it calls the Item class `use()` funtion instead.

It has been declared in the Item class like so,

```
   // ....
public:
   // ....
    virtual void use(Player&){}
   // ....
```

It has been declared in Bandage class like so,

```
   // ....
class Bandage : public Item{
public:
   // ....
    virtual void use(Player&);
   // ....
```

It has been defined in the Bandage class like so,

```
void Bandage::use(Player& player)
{
    player.heal(35);
}
```

When I attempt to call the `use()` function of my item, say for instance, `m_items.at(i).item->use(*m_player);`

It calls the base class 'Item' `use()` function, rather than the 'Bandage' `use()` function.

EDIT:
Here is my addItem function,

```
void Inventory::addItem(const Item& item)
{
    if ((m_items.size() < m_capacity))
    {
        bool foundItem(false);
        for (auto invItem : m_items)
        {
            // if the item already exists, lets just increase the quantity
            if (invItem.item->getID() == item.getID())
            {
                foundItem = true;
                if (invItem.quantity < invItem.item->getInventoryQuantityLimit())
                {
                    ++invItem.quantity;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!foundItem){
            m_items.push_back(InventoryItem{ new Item(item), 1 });
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal compilable example? It's not clear what's wrong. Try reducing the code to 2 classes, base and derived, and post it here. It may have to do with your `addItem` function.

Comment: Ok, I have shown the addItem function in my post. Do I lose access to the derived information if I pass by const ref and not a pointer?

Comment: No, virtual mechanisms works equally well for references. See my updated answer to see where (I think) the problem lies.

Comment: In addition to what's in the answers, your `std::vector<InventoryItem> m_items;` is wrong: assigning even the correct type to an entry will slice it down to an `InventoryItem`.  You can't actually have a vector of ~any-derived-type~s, the compiler has no idea how to allocate for that.  What you have to do is store pointers to them -- all struct pointers are the same, so a pointer-to-bandage works just fine, and accessing its inventoryitem base through that pointer of course also works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `addItem()` function, more precisely here:

```
m_items.push_back(InventoryItem{ new Item(item), 1 });
```

The pointer `Item*` in `InventoryItem` ends up pointing to an `Item`, and not to objects derived from `Item`, even when `item` **is** a derived object. The expression `new Item(item)` doesn't create a derived object, but invokes the (default if you haven't written it) copy constructor of `Item` with the derived object `item` as parameter. It then creates the `Item` object on the heap, returning a pointer to it.

You will be better off with a factory method that creates the required items, and get rid of the raw pointers in favor of `std::shared_ptr` (or `std::unique_ptr`, although probably here `std::shared_ptr` is better).

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, the line `new Item(item)` creates a base (`Item`), not derived object.

If you really want to *clone* your object instead of just keeping the provided pointer (better using `auto_ptr`, for example), consider adding a `clone()` function to your `Item` and derived classes:

```
class Item {
    ...
    virtual Item* clone() { return new Item(*this);}
}

class Bandage : public Item {
    ...
    virtual Bandage* clone() { return new Bandage(*this); }
}

....
m_items.push_back(InventoryItem{ item.clone(), 1 });
```

Comment: you may want to make that `virtual` and use covariant return types (i.e. `virtual Bandage* clone()  { return new Bandage(*this);}` Although the covariant return type is not strictly required here.

Comment: Thanks, did not know it is possible to change the return type in overridden virtual function like this.

Comment: Ok, so I quickly tried this - and it does work. But I think I'm going to attempt the factory method, that way I will only have one of each type of derived Item?

Comment: @Petr, I think this is the only exception (works also with references) when you indeed can, and was probably designed specifically for `clone`-like functions, so you avoid un-necessary casts later, and also have a better compile-time type checking.

Comment: @JackH, what do you mean -- only have one of each type?

Comment: Instead of creating a clone, could I just create all the items and store them, then just a pass a reference to an item if it needs adding to the inventory? EDIT:In fact I have just noticed utnapistim answer. As the item is stateless, and there is only one inventory and one player I think this is sort of approach that would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to see what may be wrong, but maybe the use of auto in your loop is messing things up. As a quick test you could try to add a static cast to verify that auto is not messing up the resolution of the virtual function.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions to this:

**First, if the items are stateless**, you can implement this so that there is only ever one item of each type in the game, and share ownership of it with all players (if items are not stateless, then a player using an item would affect inventory state for other players, or cause undefined behavior, when used on different threads).

Code changes (for a stateless items implementation):

```
struct InventoryItem{
    std::shared_ptr<Item> item; // all inventory items using
                                // this (stateless) item, will share ownership
    unsigned int quantity;
};

void Inventory::addItem(const Item& item)
{
    if ((m_items.size() < m_capacity))
    {
        // everything here is the same as your code

        if (!foundItem){
            m_items.emplace_back( &item, 1 ); // share item
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Second, if items are not stateless**, you will have to have a virtual cloning method (allowing every specialization to clone it's own specialized type.

Implementation changes:

```
class item {
    // rest of class here ...
public:
    virtual std::shared_ptr<item> clone() const = 0;
};

class bandage {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<item> clone() const override
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<item>{ new bandage{ *this } }; // use bandage copy constructor
                                     // and instantiate concrete item type
    }
};

void Inventory::addItem(const Item& item)
{
    if ((m_items.size() < m_capacity))
    {
        // everything here is the same as your code

        if (!foundItem){
            m_items.emplace_back( item.clone(), 1 ); // create specialized type
                                                  // through clone
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `emplace_back` work for aggregates? In any case, you need `&item` when emplacing back (first code snippet), as you pass a pointer.

Comment: I still don't think `emplace_back` works, see live http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f58c43268218030